# Dynamic programming algorithm to maximize job execution steps on two machines

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I have a problem that requires finding a plan to execute a job on two machines, A and B, or moving the job between machines to maximize the number of executed steps. Specifically, in each time interval, the job can be executed on A or B for a certain number of steps, or moved between machines without executing any steps. I've attached the question below.

> We have two machines, A and B, and a job J that can be executed on
> either machine A or B, or moved between the machines in each time
> interval ti of t1,..,tn. The job can execute ai > 0 steps on machine A
> or bi > 0 steps on machine B at time interval i, or it can be moved
> from one machine to the other without executing any steps.
>
> We need to design a dynamic programming algorithm that takes as input
> the lists a1,..,an and b1,..,bn representing the number of steps that
> the job can execute on machines A and B at each time interval,
> respectively. The algorithm should find a plan that maximizes the
> number of executed steps by deciding to run the job on A or B or move
> it between the machines for each time interval. The job can be
> executed on either machine A or B at time t1.

I have been trying to solve this problem using dynamic programming, but I'm having trouble defining the subproblems. Could someone please help me with this?

Here's what I've tried so far:

- I defined the subproblems as finding the maximum number of executed
  steps up to time I .
- I represented the state as OPT(i )= the maximum steps a job can
  execute from time t1 to ti
- I came up with the recurrence relation OPT(i) = OPT(i - 1) if we move
  job on time ti, otherwise OPT(i) = max(OPT(i - 1) + ai, OPT(i -
  1)+bi).

However, I'm not sure if this is correct or how to to include the requirement that "The job can be executed on either machine A or B at time t1" into the recurrence relation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your OPT function should also depend on the machine that you are currently using. We can define OPT(i,A) as the maximum steps a job can execute from time $t_1$ to $t_i$, and we are currently working on machine A.
Can you determine what OPT(1,A) and OPT(2,A) is? Similarly for machine B.
Afterwards, generalize to OPT(i,A) and OPT(i,B).